# Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect to the LinkedIn API but everytime I try to access it I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in /home/vhosts/***/test.php on
>   line 8

I'm using a free server on 000WebHost and I've read that free servers sometimes don't support OAuth.  I've tried it on another free server and I get the same error message, so my question is how can I check whether the server supports the use of OAuth?

Here is my code:

```
// Fill the keys and secrets you retrieved after registering your app
$oauth = new OAuth("abcd123456", "efgh987654");
$oauth->setToken("abcd1234-efgh987-9988", "9876abcd-123asdf-1122");

$params = array();
$headers = array();
$method = OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET;

// Specify LinkedIn API endpoint to retrieve your own profile
$url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~";

// By default, the LinkedIn API responses are in XML format. If you prefer JSON, simply       specify the format in your call
// $url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json";

// Make call to LinkedIn to retrieve your own profile
$oauth->fetch($url, $params, $method, $headers);

echo $oauth->getLastResponse();
```

The keys are just replaced with the ones on the LikedIn Developers Getting Started Guide.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OAuth is a PECL extension it must be compiled into PHP or compiled as an extension.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.installation.php
- http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth

Most servers will not have it by default since it really is not something everyone would likely use. You can ask your host to either install it or if you have the ability compile it on server if using CGI as I did. If you run phpinfo(); and look for the word OAuth it will show up if you have it, otherwise you don't.

---

**Update:** Use https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib instead of a PECL.

Comment: can we enable this oauth extension without getting help of hosting provider ?

Comment: @SagarPPanchal there are countless userland libraries that provide oauth support. It's better to use them as the above package is no longer maintained. Use the link provided at bottom of my post.

Answer (score 2):

I use hostgator for hosting and was having this problem so if your host also uses cpanel you should be able to do what I did.

Go 1 directory up from the live directory in File Manager where you can see "public_html, www, tmp". (Or click the home folder icon to the left) and in there you should find a php.ini file. edit the file adding `extension=oauth.so` to the very end and save it.

Checking phpinfo() after that you should find a section called "OAuth" and everything should work fine.

Comment: Important that you add it to the end, which was my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-oauth
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I don't think free servers allow you to run those commands and restart the server.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

For php 5.6...  First the disclaimer: you need to migrate to the latest stable php 7 ASAP and *not* run php 5.6!  But if that's just not possible quite yet, this might help Ubuntu 16.04 users. This assumes you have the ondrej/php ppa.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo apt-get install php-pear            # * see note below 
sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev          # for phpize
sudo pecl install oauth-1.2.3

# now add "extension=oauth.so" (sans quotes) to the 
# "Dynamic Extensions" area in /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
```

* Per this post
https://askubuntu.com/a/756186/343695 "php-pear pull[s] just CLI PHP 7.0 (php7.0-cli) and that's harmless"  That comment was made in 2016 and may no longer be true.  I didn't see any problems...yet.