# Error 401 with Php cUrl request by Oauth 1.0

Tags: php, curl, oauth

I want to get a json from an API of a Magento Eshop. I tried to retrieve this by Php cUrl but i ahev a 401 error retrieved by the json.
I already have **consumer_key, consumer_secret, token and token_secret** generated by the app on my account on the supplier website. I put them in the header but I have this returned:

```
// 20190207092925
// http://localhost/inart-REST/myapi.php

{
  "messages": {
    "error": [
      {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "oauth_problem=version_rejected"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can't figure out why, beacuse on Postman it return me all json with a 200 status code.

Comment: This is a duplicate, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822406/fatal-error-class-oauth-not-found-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822406/fatal-error-class-oauth-not-found-in)

Comment: I saw this solutions but it stuill doesn't work. The api that I retrieved is from magento and how you can see use the OAuth class. In the library mentioned in the topic it is really different and I can't apply to my script.

Comment: The fatal error is referring to a not found OAuth class. OAuth requires installation. Did you install it? https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth

Comment: I tryed but it doesn't work. I put the dll in the php ext folder and add the string i the php.ini but not showing in phpinfo

Comment: Are you using PHP as Apache Module? What is Apache's error log saying? Are you getting any warnings when executing PHP from CLI?

Comment: I use xampp. I put the dll in the ext folder and then added extension=php_oauth.dll in the php.ini. Then i launch my file.php that has phpinfo funztion and inside i haven't any Oauth extension. In my script with Oauth i retrieve error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'OAuth' not found" in the line where i instanciate the Oauth class

Comment: Without providing any more information I cannot help you. My guess is, that the extension cannot be loaded and thus OAuth is not available.

Comment: I just tested it and could successfully load oauth 2.0.3 with PHP 7.1.26.^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187950/discussion-between-lisarko8077-and-arueckauer).